# Grabbing values from a file to see if they are int or string

Tags: c++

I've trying to grab a value from a file and see if it's an int or a string. if its a int it should go into the tempNum var if it's a string it should go into the tempString var. The rest of my code is written i just need to get that value into the correct variable.

```
while (!myFile.eof())
{

    try
    {
        myFile >> tempNum;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument&)
    {
        myfile >> tempString;
    }


}
```

Second attempt:

```
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("data.txt");

    while (myFile >> tempString)
    {
        tempNum = -1;
        tempString = "-0";
        bool isInteger = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < tempString.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (!isdigit(tempString[i]))
            {
                isInteger = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isInteger)
        {
            tempNum = stoi(tempString);
            if (tempNum != -1)
            cout << tempNum;
        }
        if (tempString != "-0")
        cout << tempString;

    }
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: What is the format of the file?  ASCII text?  If so, can we assume that there will be no strings in the file that consist solely of numeric digits?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It's just a .txt file so i would assume so

Comment: In that case, just always read it in as a string, then examine the string to see if it consists solely of numeric digits, and if it does, convert it to an int with atoi() (or whatever string-to-int conversion function you prefer to use).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Check out the code above. I tried to do that and it seems to not be working because its printing out nothing.

Comment: Why are you setting tempString to "-0" before analyzing the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from a file, you should be reading it into a string:

```
while (fileVar >> myString)
{
   // Do something with the string from file
}
```

So, you can test for each individual character to see what the whole is. Below is how to separate only the int's. Otherwise, if you want separate strings that contain only letters, then replace the "[isdigit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)" function with "[isalpha()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)", or test for specific characters.

```
// Input validation (int)
bool isInteger = true;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); ++i)
{
    if (!isdigit(myString[i]))
    {
        isInteger = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isInteger)
{
   int myInt = stoi(myString);
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work, am i doing something wrong?(added code in original post)

Comment: @SaladSnake The first 2 assignments should be moved to before the while loop. The condition of the while loop simply says "while not the end of file, read the next thing from the file and assign it to a string". So, that string will contain the next thing at the beginning of the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (myFile >> tempNum) {
  // it worked as an int
} else if (myfile >> tempString) {
  // it worked as a string
}
```

Comment: really it's that easy? wont it throw an error the first if statement?

Comment: It will not throw an exception.

Comment: It works but doesn't go to the next word in the file just like my try catch.